# I am finding "getVideoViewRate" from "Metrics"

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am trying to get Video Data but some "Metrics" data I can't get.
So please help me with that?

```
$query = "SELECT campaign.id, ad_group.id, ad_group.name, metrics.impressions, metrics.video_views, metrics.clicks, metrics.video_view_rate, metrics.average_cpv, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.video_quartile_p25_rate, metrics.video_quartile_p50_rate, metrics.video_quartile_p75_rate, metrics.video_quartile_p100_rate, ad_group.status FROM ad_group WHERE ad_group.id IN (11111222233)";

        // Issues a search request by specifying page size.
        $response = $googleAdsServiceClient->search($customerId, $query, ['pageSize' => self::PAGE_SIZE]);

        // Iterates over all rows in all pages and prints the requested field values for each row.
        foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
            /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */
            printf(
                "Ad group ID %d in campaign ID %d group Status %d Impressions %d clicks %d video_view %d video_view_rate %d average_cpv %d cost_micros %d video_quartile_p25_rate %d video_quartile_p50_rate %d video_quartile_p75_rate %d video_quartile_p100_rate %d ",
                $googleAdsRow->getAdGroup()->getId(),
                $googleAdsRow->getCampaign()->getId(),
                $googleAdsRow->getAdGroup()->getStatus(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getImpressions(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoViews(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoViewRate(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getAverageCpv(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getCostMicros(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoQuartileP25Rate(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoQuartileP50Rate(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoQuartileP75Rate(),
                $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getVideoQuartileP100Rate(),
                PHP_EOL
            );
```

**OUTPUT IS:**

Ad group ID  11111222233   in campaign ID  11111222233   group Status 3 Impressions 10552 clicks 2 video_view 6225 video_view_rate 0 average_cpv 20862 cost_micros 129871561 video_quartile_p25_rate 0 video_quartile_p50_rate 0 video_quartile_p75_rate 0 video_quartile_p100_rate 0

**I need video_view_rate, video_quartile_p25_rate, video_quartile_p50_rate, video_quartile_p75_rate, video_quartile_p100_rate**

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thanks for the support. I find out this solution. 
There is my mistake I have used %d it's return numbers value only.
%s is return string and Google Ads Api return stats in string.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is my mistake I have used %d it's return numbers value only. %s is return string and Google Ads Api return stats in string.